# Star rating (plugin) style does not get applied if I create dynamic listview in JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a dynamic listivew and add a star rating for each item in the listview. If i create a static listivew everything is displayed correctly, but if i create it dynamically it does not show the stars rating, instead it shows radio buttons. Below is the scripts and css included in my code.

```
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.rating.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This is my HTML page that contains only the ul element and the listview gets added dynamically

```
<div data-role="page" id="mypage">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a id="btnLink" href="#"  rel="external" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a>
        <h1 id="venHeader"></h1>
        <a id="btnHome" href="index.html" rel="external" data-icon="home">Home</a> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="vendorlist" data-role="listview" data-list-icon="gear" data-filter="true">
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

And below is my script

```
<script>
$("#mypage").live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
    $.post("jquery-mobile/getvalue.jsp",
    {
        struser:"username",
        password:"password"
    },
    function(data,status){
        if(status="success"){
            var rowdata = data.split("|"); // | is the row delimiter
            var vendorlist="";
            $.each(rowdata,function(i, rowelement){
                var columndata = rowelement.split("::"); // :: is the column delimiter
                if(i>0){
                    var list = '<li>' +              
                        '<div class="checkBoxLeft">' +
                            '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" class="hidden-checkbox"/>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<a href="#" class="detailListText">' +
                            '<h3>'+columndata[2]+'</h3>' +
                            '<span class="ui-li-aside" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">' +
                                '<input data-role="none" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" title=""/>' +
                                '<input data-role="none" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" title=""/>' +
                                '<input data-role="none" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" title=""/>' +
                                '<input data-role="none" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" title=""/>' +
                                '<input data-role="none" name="star1" type="radio" class="star" title=""/>' +
                            '</span>' +
                            '<p>'+columndata[3]+'</p>' +
                        '</a>' +
                        '</a><a href="#" data-icon="home"></a>' +
                    '</li>';
                    vendorlist = vendorlist+list;
                };
            });
            $("#vendorlist").append(vendorlist);
            $("#vendorlist").listview("refresh");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Can you please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Can someone please help me with this issue??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To implement Star Rating, I have changed my code. Now I am using Rateit plugin http://rateit.codeplex.com/.
Below is the script that solved my problem.

```
<script>
$("#mypage").live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
    $.post("jquery-mobile/getvalue.jsp",
    {
        struser:"username",
        password:"password"
    },
    function(data,status){
        if(status="success"){
            var rowdata = data.split("|"); // | is the row delimiter
            var vendorlist="";
            $.each(rowdata,function(i, rowelement){
                var columndata = rowelement.split("::"); // :: is the column delimiter
                if(i>0){
                    var list = '<li>' +              
                        '<div class="checkBoxLeft">' +
                            '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0" id="checkbox-0" class="hidden-checkbox"/>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<a href="#" class="detailListText">' +
                            '<h3>'+columndata[2]+'</h3>' +
                            '<span class="ui-li-aside" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">' +
                                '<div class="rateit"></div>' +
                            '</span>' +
                            '<p>'+columndata[3]+'</p>' +
                        '</a>' +
                        '</a><a href="#" data-icon="home"></a>' +
                    '</li>';
                    vendorlist = vendorlist+list;
                };
            });
            $("#vendorlist").append(vendorlist);
            $("#vendorlist").listview("refresh");
            $('.rateit').rateit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

In order to "activate" the rateit control for items that have been added to the dom after domready, you'll simply need to call **$('.rateit').rateit();** after you've loaded your listview.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that after inserting the new HTML you needed to invoke the plugin again.

After this...

```
$("#vendorlist").append(vendorlist);
$("#vendorlist").listview("refresh");
```

You needed to to this....

```
    $('.star').rating();
```

Which is what you did with the new plugin. Either plugin would work.